# The child IMAGE behind the parent DIV. How?

Tags: html, css

I have an image inside a `div`. I need that child image to be behind the parent `div`.

```
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://gsa-cmp-fileupload.s3.amazonaws.com/USA_Government_Branches_Infographic.png" class="child" />
</div>
```

That image should be behind that *red* border. How to do it?

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  }

.parent img.child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <img src="https://gsa-cmp-fileupload.s3.amazonaws.com/USA_Government_Branches_Infographic.png" class="child" />
    </div>
```

[image: This is what I need.]

I was looking for it for a long time, but still cannot understand how to do it. Please, provide some help.

Comment: seems more like a `background-image` in stead of an `<img>` to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do it like this :

```
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
   overflow:hidden;
  }
```